# Fuzzy Relation Projection and cylindrical extension

Tags: projection, relation, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to study all possible conditions that from **projections** of a **Fuzzy relation** R defined on X1 x X2 x .... Xn we can get back to the **original relation** R.

Does anyone have any idea about it?
I searched very much, but all I got was this sentence: "such situation is very rare!"

I need the answer as soon a possible

Thank you all

Comment: Welcome to SO.e. If you bother to read the description of the [tag:fuzzy] tag, you will see that it is requested that you do not use it for new questions and that instead use one that is less ambiguous. You may edit your question with the 'edit' button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: it is the specific problem. I can't change the question.